# How do I pass data to an error handler?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I want to create an error handler that sets the body of the response depending on the nature of the error. Something like this:

```
@the_error = Hash.new

get '/' do
 @the_error[:message] = "error message"
 400
end

error 400 do
 @the_error[:message]
end
```

But this doesn't work as expected (the `@the_error` variable is `Nil` when in the get handler). What am I doing wrong, or perhaps there's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use built-in [settings](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html) for this:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :the_error, Hash.new

get '/' do
  options.the_error[:message] = "error message"
  400
end

error 400 do
  options.the_error[:message]
end
```